# Showing all posts from a specific category

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want to create "view all posts" link to show all posts of a specific category in wordpress.

But as a newcomer I can't handle it. Can you tell me to create that type of link, which code should I write in functions.php file and which code should I write in page to create and show the link to visitors. Please make clear answer. I am very new,please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the plugin [Display Posts Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/).

- Create a page and add the shortcode to it
- Add a link to that page in the menu f your choice